# I can't access object key because of - sign?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I want to reach the "official-artwork" key returned from the API, but I cannot reach the "official-artwork" key due to the - sign. How can I access keys of this type?

```
official-artwork: {value}
```

Comment: There are already multiple questions and answers on this topic, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869627/unable-to-access-json-property-with-dash) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148423/json-contains-minus-char-is-this-valid-standard).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```js
item?.sprites.other['official-artwork']
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in block & quotes:

```
item?.sprites.other["official-artwork"]
```